# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout in espresso test

Tags: android, fragment, android-espresso, androidx

I have a fragment with which has a TabLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/playerSectionsTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabRippleColor="@null"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance" />
```

and I'm using:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and it works fine. But it doesn't work in espresso tests and I get this:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
```

BTW I use fragment-testing package to test my fragments.

Comment: Check this out.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346748/robolectric-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or